# TeX system for Windows server

Tags: windows, distributions

I'm trying to find a TeX system for the following Windows version:

> Windows Server Datacenter
>       Copyright 2007 Microsoft Corperation
>       Service Pack 2

I tried with MiKTeX but seems it is not compatible with this version.
Any suggestion would be great.

---

**Edit:**

The server is Amazon aws cloud server. And that's the operation system details I can find on the server. 
(*Windows Server Datacenter
Copyright 2007 Microsoft Corperation
Service Pack 2*)

And this is the error it  throws when I try to install MiKTeX

```
The operation could not be completed for the following reason:
Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
Details: C:\Programe Files\MiKTeX2.9\tpm\pakages\a%comb.tpm
```

Comment: Two common distributions are MikTeX and TeX Live. Without additional information it's very hard to tell what's wrong with your setup. What steps do you take? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Rasika: Please edit your question to add more details instead of posting it as an answer. I mode the text to keep the site tidy. Thanks.

Comment: I am still confused about your OS.  Could you follow [these instructions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/which-version-of-the-windows-operating-system-am-i-running) and update the question?  Maybe with a screenshot of the resulting window.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MiKTeX 2.9 setup page](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup):

> The following Windows platforms are
>   supported:
>
> - Windows 7
> - Windows Vista with Service Pack 2 (all editions except Starter Edition)
> - Windows XP with Service Pack 3 (all editions except Starter Edition)
> - Windows Server 2008 R2
> - Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 2
> - Windows Server 2003 R2
> - Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 2

I don't know what "Windows Server Datacenter, copyright 2007" means, but I would suspect if MiKTeX installs in all of these it should install in yours.  Have you tried it?

Comment: "Datacenter" are special editions of Windows Server since 2000 -- unless the submitter uses such an ancient version, it's most likely Windows Server 2003 R2.